# Send Notification to pidgin via python 2.4

Tags: python, pidgin

In my application I want to send notifications to users through their pidgin internet messanger using python 2.4.

Does anyone can show some light on how this can be done?

Comment: Do you want to send a message to the user on the current pc, or to send a message from him to another user? Or to display just some kind of notification?

Comment: @Tisho I want to send message from him to another user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code using dbus (with Python 2.7, cannot test it with 2.4), but the problem is that it opens a conversation window. I haven't find a way to hide/close/minimize the window.

```
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
purple_obj = session_bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService",
                                    "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple_int = dbus.Interface(purple_obj, 
                            "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")
my_account_id = purple_int.PurpleAccountsGetAllActive()[0] # or some other account from yours
conv = purple_int.PurpleConversationNew(1, my_account_id, "recipient's email")
conv_im = purple_int.PurpleConvIm(conv)
purple_int.PurpleConvImSend(conv_im, "This is your message")
```

Comment: can we implement this like sending message from a server to user

Comment: As long as you have pidgin installed, and an account set up - I guess so. You'll just need to start it, so it will probably need a graphic session...haven't tested it in such environment.